# Configure postgraphile to support succinct nested mutations

Tags: postgraphile

I have come to postgraphile yesterday from a couple of years with Hasura.  I was stunned at what PG does out of the box.  My main sense of loss is around the GQL api that PG offers, relative to Hasura.  If I have  Customer with a foreign key to an Address, and I add the nested mutations plugin,  I can say this:

```
mutation MyMutation {
  createCustomer(
    input: {customer: {addressToAddressId: {create: {line1: "5", line2: "The Street"}}, firstName: "Breda", lastName: "Smith"}}
  ) {
    address {
      id
    }
    customer {
      id
    }
  }
}
```

But with Hasura I would be able to say something like :

```
mutation MyMutation {
  createCustomer(input:{firstName: "Breda", lastName: "Smith", address:{line1: "5", line2: "The Street"}}) {
    address {
      id
    }
    customer {
      id
    }
  }
}
```

How can I configure PG so it can do this kind of mutation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I asked on the postgraphile discord channel, and [Benjie replied](https://discord.com/channels/489127045289476126/498852330754801666/1061355590615568544):

It’d be possible to write a plugin to do this, but I’m not a big fan of CRUD mutations in general. I’d do it this way:

The first way to consider adding a mutation to your GraphQL schema is with a Custom Mutations. These create individual highly specialised mutations from the VOLATILE functions in your PostgreSQL database. There's a checklist of requirements they must meet defined in their [documentation](https://www.graphile.org/postgraphile/custom-mutations/) .

If this doesn't suit your needs, you may also using [makeExtendSchemaPlugin](https://www.graphile.org/postgraphile/make-extend-schema-plugin/#mutation-example)  or have a look through the [community plugins](https://www.graphile.org/postgraphile/community-plugins/)to see if one suits your needs. Relevant reading on [GraphQL mutation design](https://medium.com/@__xuorig__/graphql-mutation-design-anemic-mutations-dd107ba70496)